# How to create file in Node.js without saving

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is it possible in node.js to bind a file to a variable without saving it to the hard disk, as we get it in req.files?

Comment: What do you mean by file? If it is a file it is already on the hard disk. You can of course read it to memory

Comment: @A.Llorente Im sorry if I poorly formulated the question. I want to create a csv file and upload it immediately using aws-sdk without saving on hard disk.

Comment: I guess that depends on aws-sdk but I am sure you can just send it as raw data, but that has more to do with aws-sdk than with node itself.

Comment: I think to send it to aws, you may need save the file temporarily if is passing by a backend. At least the client uploads it directly to aws, that probably is not the case